# BackendIdConverter not resolving to Entity

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

**Overview**

I've got an `@Entity` with an `@EmbeddedId` composite key. The entities are exposed over a REST api which uses a `BackendIdConverter` to convert the id string back to an instance of the `@Embeddable` composite key. My understanding is that this is then used to identify an instance of the `@Entity`, but that isn't happening.

**Question**

How is the `@Embeddable` composite key resolved back to an `@Entity`?

**Code**

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity {

    @EmbeddedId
    private MyEntityIdentifier id;
```

---

```
@Embeddable
public class MyEntityIdentifier implements Serializable {

    public static final String COMPOSITE_KEY_DELIMITER = "_@_";

    @Column
    private String idPartOne;

    @Column
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date idPartTwo;
```

---

```
@Component
public class StringToMyEntityIdentifierConverter implements BackendIdConverter {

    @Override
    public Serializable fromRequestId(String id, Class<?> aClass) {
        String[] split = id.split(COMPOSITE_KEY_DELIMITER);
        String idPartOne = split[0];
        Date idPartTwo = Date.valueOf(split[1]);
        return new MyEntityIdentifier(fullName, lastUpdated);
    }
```

---

```
public interface MyEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, MyEntityIdentifier> {

}
```

Comment: What happens when you call the repository's `findById(MyEntityIdentifier id)` method?

Comment: do you mean `findOne(Id id)` or is findById a method I need to provide?

Comment: Yes, try calling `findOne` with the composite key.